# Retaining cookies and session with Python does not work

Tags: python, session, cookies, python-requests

I am attempting to stay logged in while using requests in Python. I have tried using sessions and cookies, but I keep gettin a 413 Invalid session error. Here is my code:

```
import requests


s = requests.Session()
url = "http://"+edge_server+":7780/xtvschedule/rest//UserManager/Login"
rsp = s.post(url, json = Body1, auth=("1002","0123"))
print (rsp.status_code)
cookie = rsp.cookies


url ="http://"+edge_server+":7780/xtvschedule/rest//ContentManager/BrowseRecordedAssets"
rsp = s.get(url,cookies=cookie)
print(rsp.status_code)
print(rsp.content)
```

Thank You for the help!

Here is the same api running on soapui correctly with the cookies:
[image: 1]

Comment: What have you already done to debug the error? What cookies are set / retransmitted / required?

Comment: this is the cookie that is sent : <Cookie JSESSIONID=IbIlGvffzYaCj8WyxbvISs5EhbdFxvtf5L28aau8o7qxuB-N2cfZ!-1618994222 for 192.168.9.194/xtvschedule>

Comment: Next time, add all relevant information to the question itself. It looks like the port is missing in the cookie.

Comment: how would I include the port in the cookie